# How to get value from dataGridView which is imported from .xls file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datagridview

I have an application that allow me to import .xls/.xlsx file into a gridView. The .xls/.xlsx file is successfully imported into a gridView.

There are a columns named Date, Name and Total in my gridView.
How can I get the value from that dataGridView? I want to get all the data, so I can count the data in Total Column group by date and name.
Can I loop the data and store it into variable?

Comment: You can loop over gridview  `foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspired with your answer.
So, here is my resolution :

```
For data As Integer = 0 To InvestorGridView.Rows.Count - 1 

Response.Wri‌​te(InvestorGridView.Rows(data).Cells(0).Text)

Response.Wri‌​te(InvestorGridView.Rows(data).Cells(1).Text)

Response.Wri‌​te(InvestorGridView.Rows(data).Cells(2).Text)

Next
```